# Determining the velocity of an arrow.

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

The acceleration of an arrow from a bow falls from $6000$ $ms^{-2}$
(when the bowstring is fully
drawn back) to zero when it leaves the bow after travelling a distance $x$ = 0.75m. Assuming
that this acceleration can be expressed by the linear equation: $a$ = $6000[1 - (4x/3)]$ $ms^{-2}$
determine the speed of the arrow when it leaves the bow.

I tried to use the differential equation which relates acceleration, velocity and position (which
applies regardless of whether the acceleration is constant or not) and tried integrating the expression. However I wasn't able to get the final answer of $v$=$67.1 m/s$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the corresponding energy equation,
Change in Kinetic Energy= Work done in the path
Mass gets cancelled out and you get the following form,
(v^2)/2=6000x-4000x^2,
which should give you the required answer (67.1m/s) if you put x=0.75, provided your calculations are correct

Comment: How can i use the work done equation when there is no force involved? @TheFool

Comment: Acceleration **always** involves force for massive objects. Newton's second: $F=ma$. The force is provided by the bow: that is its function.

Comment: Gert is completely right. Also, if you have trouble wrapping your head around this particular idea, you can simply take a more mathematical approach by equating the given expression for acceleration with VdV/dX and integrating. As you have said that you have already used it, I think you should recheck it as this differential equation should give you the same expression as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration can be written as $\frac{dv}{dt}=v\frac{dv}{dx}$. Equate this to the expression you have been given then solve to find $v(x)$.

Possibly this is what you have already done. Apologies to the Fool : I did not see your comment before posting this.